# Hi , I am fairly new to Solr search and when I try to crawl a web page, it is giving me following error

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr-search

Running it on mac terminal and following error comes up:

Website I am using is https://factorpad.com/tech/solr/index.html

```
 > Ravishers-MacBook-Air:solr-8.6.3 ravishersingh$ bin/post -c solrhelp
    > -filetypes html https://factorpad.com/tech/solr/index.html java -classpath /Users/ravishersingh/downloads/solr-8.6.3/dist/solr-core-8.6.3.jar
    > -Dauto=yes -Dfiletypes=html -Dc=solrhelp -Ddata=web org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool
    > https://factorpad.com/tech/solr/index.html SimplePostTool version
    > 5.0.0 Posting web pages to Solr url http://localhost:8983/solr/solrhelp/update/extract Entering auto mode.
    > Indexing pages with content-types corresponding to file endings html
    > Entering crawl at level 0 (1 links total, 1 new) SimplePostTool:
    > WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url:
    > http://localhost:8983/solr/solrhelp/update/extract?literal.id=https%3A%2F%2Ffactorpad.com%2Ftech%2Fsolr%2Findex.html&literal.url=https%3A%2F%2Ffactorpad.com%2Ftech%2Fsolr%2Findex.html
    > SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html> <head> <meta
    > http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    > <title>Error 404 Not Found</title> </head> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404
    > Not Found</h2> <table>
    > <tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/solrhelp/update/extract</td></tr>
    > <tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>404</td></tr> <tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Not
    > Found</td></tr> <tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr> </table>
    > 
    > </body> </html> SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading
    > response: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
    > http://localhost:8983/solr/solrhelp/update/extract?literal.id=https%3A%2F%2Ffactorpad.com%2Ftech%2Fsolr%2Findex.html&literal.url=https%3A%2F%2Ffactorpad.com%2Ftech%2Fsolr%2Findex.html
    > SimplePostTool: WARNING: An error occurred while posting
    > https://factorpad.com/tech/solr/index.html 0 web pages indexed.
    > COMMITting Solr index changes to
    > http://localhost:8983/solr/solrhelp/update/extract... SimplePostTool:
    > WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url:
    > http://localhost:8983/solr/solrhelp/update/extract?commit=true
    > SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html> <head> <meta
    > http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    > <title>Error 404 Not Found</title> </head> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404
    > Not Found</h2> <table>
    > <tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/solrhelp/update/extract</td></tr>
    > <tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>404</td></tr> <tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Not
    > Found</td></tr> <tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr> </table>
    > 
    > </body> </html> Time spent: 0:00:01.044
    > Ravishers-MacBook-Air:solr-8.6.3 ravishersingh$
```

Any guidance in right direction to resolve issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no core named `solrhelp` - or your Solr instance is borked. Does `http://localhost:8983/solr/` give anything if you open it in a browser?

Comment: yes. I do have solrhelp core. and when I go to http://localhost:8983/solr/ it shows instance of solr running

Comment: In that case you may not have loaded the libraries and configuration required to enable the extracting request handler (the `/extract` endpoint: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#UploadingDatawithSolrCellusingApacheTika-ConfiguringtheSolrExtractingRequestHandler)

Comment: Depending on your setup these files may reside in Zookeeper